# How to stream video from different files?

Tags: python, node.js, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have a remote folder with videos in it. Videos are being upload continuously.

For example:

```
[1].avi
[2].avi
[3].avi
[4].avi
```

I want to be able to stream these videos as closest to real time as possible (using rtsp or something similar)

In this case I can start streaming number 2, then 3 and so on... And checking the folder for updates.

I've done a python script that allows me to reproduce all these videos one after another, without noticing the change between them, using OpenCV (cv2). But I still have no idea how can I make the streaming.

```
import numpy as np
import collections
import cv
import os


__FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 10.0

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

def play(file):
    vidFile = cv.CaptureFromFile(file)
    nFrames = int(  cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) )
    fps = cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS )
    waitPerFrameInMillisec = int( 1/__FRAMES_PER_SECOND * 1000/1 )
    for f in xrange( nFrames ):
      frameImg = cv.QueryFrame( vidFile )
      cv.ShowImage( "My Video Window",  frameImg )
      cv.WaitKey( waitPerFrameInMillisec  )



directory = "vids/"
dictFiles = {}
arrFiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    #print root
    #print dirs
    arrFiles = files    
for file in arrFiles:
    number = find_between(file, "[", "]")
    #print "----------",file
    dictFiles[number] = file

orderedDictFiles = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dictFiles.items()))
for file in orderedDictFiles:
    play(directory + orderedDictFiles[file])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you can use the `pyinotify` 3rd party module to play videos as they are uploaded.

The following code prints `"video complete: <pathname>"` when a video file is completely uploaded.  It can be modified to play the video file.

### source

```
import os, sys

import pyinotify

class VideoComplete(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        sys.stdout.write(
            'video complete: {}\n'.format(event.pathname)
        )
        sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(
        wm, default_proc_fun=VideoComplete(),
        )
    mask = pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/incoming')
    wm.add_watch(path, mask, rec=True, auto_add=True)
    notifier.loop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### output

```
video complete: /home/johnm/Downloads/incoming/a.txt
```

Comment: Excellent. Is there a way ti do it for the web?

Comment: @JuanmaCrescente: the above code could push URLs to a WebSocket connected to a user's browser. The browser would then fetch and play the video URL.  Rather a bit of work but it would look cool :)